# How to fix a FileNotFoundError while accessing files in a corpus

Tags: python, corpus, file-not-found

I'm trying to write code that access files from a corpus called Mini-CORE. I had no problems printing the `listdir` and extracting the genre codes from them. However, when I try to access the files themselves to extract the text It's giving me `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1+IN+EN+IN-IN-IN-IN+EN-EN-EN-EN+WIKI+9990014.txt'` which is the first file name in the folder. So I'm confused why it's telling me the filename if it's claiming it doesn't exist? Have I just made a syntax error somewhere?

```
import os
import re
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from collections import Counter

nlp = spacy.load('en')

entries = os.listdir('Mini-CORE')
entry_list = []

# this returns the genre codes for each file
def genre_code(filename):
    for entry in entries:
        regex1 = r'((?<=1\+)\w*)'  # This captures the genre code
        genre = re.findall(regex1, entry)
        entry_list.append(genre)
genre_code(entries)
print(entry_list)


# FileNotFoundError???
# This captures the text after after the <h> or <p> tags
def relevant_text(filename):
        for filename in entries:
            with open(filename) as current_file:
                text = current_file.read()
                regex2 = r'((?<=<h>|<p>).*)'
                text2 = re.findall(regex2, text)
                print(text2)

print(relevant_text(entries))
```

Comment: `listdir` results do not include the path to the file. You would want to add `os.path.join('Mini-CORE', filename)` to each of the names put into `entries`. `relevant_text()` seems buggy. You pass in a `filename` but immediately overwrite that with filenames from `entries`. That makes it hard to write an answer without propegating that presumed bug.

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir` returns the filename without its path. You need the file's parent directory when opening the file. `pathlib` is a object oriented path library that makes it easier to pass paths around without worrying about directory and path names.

Use `Path.glob` to list the directory and the returned paths will have both the file name and its path available for your program to use. With some cleanup your code could be

```
from pathlib import Path
import re
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from collections import Counter

nlp = spacy.load('en')

entries = Path('Mini-CORE').glob("*")

# this returns the genre codes for each file
def genre_code(entries):
    entry_list = []
    for entry in entries:
        regex1 = r'((?<=1\+)\w*)'  # This captures the genre code
        genre = re.findall(regex1, entry.name)
        entry_list.append(genre)
    return entry_list
    
entry_list = genre_code(entries)
print(entry_list)

# This captures the text after after the <h> or <p> tags
def relevant_text(entries):
        for filename in entries:
            with open(filename) as current_file:
                text = current_file.read()
                regex2 = r'((?<=<h>|<p>).*)'
                text2 = re.findall(regex2, text)
                print(text2)

print(relevant_text(entries))
```